# Add a column of tabs into a tab-separated file

Tags: bash, sed, awk

Input is a tab-separated file (here spaces but whatever):

```
Sample1 ACGGGGCGCAGCAGGCGCGA text other122
something ABCDSDDADASDASDSAD hjas 23823sss
ahsdksads AHJHJDHSJHJDALKDLK hello world
```

What I want to do is to add a column of tabs after the first column. So basically:

```
Sample1<TAB><TAB>ACGGGGCGCAGCAGGCGCGA<TAB>text<TAB>other122
something<TAB><TAB>ABCDSDDADASDASDSAD<TAB>hjas<TAB>23823sss
ahsdksads<TAB><TAB>AHJHJDHSJHJDALKDLK<TAB>hello<TAB>world
```

sed/awk preferred but whatever goes..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS="\t"} $2="\t"$2' file
Sample1         ACGGGGCGCAGCAGGCGCGA text other122
something       ABCDSDDADASDASDSAD hjas 23823sss
ahsdksads       AHJHJDHSJHJDALKDLK hello world
```

Which is exactly the same as `awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS="\t"} $1=$1"\t"'`. That is, it either appends one tab to the end of 1st field or to the beginning of the 2nd one.

Also

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS="\t"} $2=FS$2' file
```

Comment: That would convert every other tab in the fie to a single space. Set FS and OFS.

Comment: Thanks @EdMorton, just added `BEGIN{OFS=FS="\t"}`.

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\t/&&/' file
```

or:

```
awk '{sub(/\t/,"&&")}1' file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/<TAB>/<TAB><TAB>/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want two tabs after the first column:

```
 sed 's/\([^ \t]*\) \([^ \t]*\)/\1\t\2/g' foo.txt | sed 's/\t/\t\t/'
```

Answer (score 0):

You change the output field seperator to a tab, and and an extra tab after the first element:

`awk -v 'OFS=\t' '$1=$1"\t"'`

Answer (score 0):

Pure bash solution:

```
filename='file.txt'
tempFile="/tmp/my_script_$RANDOM"
while read -r line; do
    printf "%s\n" "${line/  /       }" >> "$tempFile" # should be ${line/<TAB>/<TAB><TAB>}
done < "$filename"
mv -f -- "$tempFile" "$filename"
```